# How to prevent native validation of @mui TextField when required?

Tags: reactjs, validation, material-ui, react-hook-form, yup

How can I prevent the default validation (the default warning message) in @mui TextField component when it is marked as required?
[image: default warning]

I don't need this message since I am validating my form using yup and react-hook-form.

libs:

- @mui/material: "^5.14.4"
- yup: "^1.3.3"
- react-hook-form: "^7.47.0"

```
<FormProvider {...methods}>
   <Dialog
    open={true}
    {...props}
    PaperProps={{
       ...PaperProps,
       component: 'form',
       onSubmit,
    }}
    >
        ...
    <DialogContent>
        <TextField
        {...methods.register('title')}
        className="col-span-full"
        required        
        error={!!methods.formState?.errors?.title?.message}
        helperText={methods.formState?.errors?.title?.message?.toString()}
         />
    </DialogContent>
</FormProvider>
```

**Approach 1:**
As in material docs: [mui text field](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-text-field/):

```
<Box
      component="form"
      sx={{
        '& .MuiTextField-root': { m: 1, width: '25ch' },
      }}
      noValidate
      autoComplete="off"
    >
      <div>
        <TextField
          error
          id="outlined-error"
          label="Error"
          defaultValue="Hello World"
        />
     </div>
</Box>
```

I should use `noValidate` attribute inside my `Dialog` component which is of type form:

```
<Dialog
    open={true}
    {...props}
    PaperProps={{
       ...PaperProps,
       component: 'form',
       noValidate,
       onSubmit,
    }}
>
```

but it throws me error:

> noValidate is not defined.

**Approach 2:**
I tried to prevent the default behavior when submitting form:

```
const handleFormSubmit: SubmitHandler<AccountSetApiPayload> = (data, event: FormEvent) => {
   event.preventDefault();
}
```

but it doesn't work this way.